# How to change close button orientation in JvTabBar1?

Tags: delphi, vcl, jedi

How to move the close button at the right side in JvTabBar1 (JVCL component)?

In this component does not provide a choice of accommodation side.

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: JvTabBar's look is driven by the assigned `Painter`. By default it's used the `TJvModernTabBarPainter`, which if you modify, can display the close buttons on the right side. If you include [`this class intercept`](http://pastebin.com/kxHuChuU) into your form code, if will show what you're asking (take it just as a proof). But better derive your own painter.

Comment: Why use that non standard control at all?

Comment: @TLama, it`s work! Thanks! :) David Heffernan, Standard component has no function a close button

Comment: Fair enough. I had not realised that. There are various examples out there of how to owner draw the tab to achieve that. But using this control seems like a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a modernized JvTabBar.pas which has this feature, and some others.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21972495/2051938