# TabBar whose style can be changed dynamically based on JvTabBar

Tags: delphi, canvas, png, jvcl

I have tried many different libraries, but none came.
None of them can not be specified without introducing his own style in Painter.
I need to be able to quickly and dynamically change the style tab.

In response, I showed my developments.

If someone has similar developments - write them in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to upgrade the simplest of them: TJvTabBar of JVCL (latest revision: 13415)

Here is the result.

**Before (default)**

[image: default style]

**After**

[image: mod]

[image: description]

**Style sources (All graphics imported from png files with transparency)**

[image: sources]

**Easy apply any personal style to any JvTabBar**

```
var tmp:TStrings;
begin    
  tmp:=TStringList.Create;
  tmp.Values['TOP_background']:=                ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-TOP_background.png';
  tmp.Values['TOP_active_left_side']:=          ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-TOP_active_left_side.png';
  tmp.Values['TOP_active_right_side']:=         ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-TOP_active_right_side.png';
  tmp.Values['TOP_active_center']:=             ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-TOP_active_center.png';

  tmp.Values['BOTTOM_background']:=             ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-BOTTOM_background.png';
  tmp.Values['BOTTOM_active_left_side']:=       ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-BOTTOM_active_left_side.png';
  tmp.Values['BOTTOM_active_right_side']:=      ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-BOTTOM_active_right_side.png';
  tmp.Values['BOTTOM_active_center']:=          ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-BOTTOM_active_center.png';

  tmp.Values['CLOSEBUTTON_normal']:=            ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-CLOSEBUTTON_normal.png';
  tmp.Values['CLOSEBUTTON_selected']:=          ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-CLOSEBUTTON_selected.png';
  tmp.Values['CLOSEBUTTON_disabled']:=          ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-CLOSEBUTTON_disabled.png';
  tmp.Values['CLOSEBUTTON_closing']:=           ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-CLOSEBUTTON_closing.png';
  tmp.Values['CLOSEBUTTON_modified']:=          ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-CLOSEBUTTON_modified.png';
  tmp.Values['CLOSEBUTTON_closing_modified']:=  ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\tabs-CLOSEBUTTON_closing_modified.png';

  JvTabBar1.StyleImages:=tmp;

  tmp.Values['BOTTOM_background']:=             ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\skins\default\MYMOD_tabs-BOTTOM_background.png';

  JvTabBar2.StyleImages:=tmp;
```

**Main changes**

- Added ability to specify their own style ( JvTabBar1.StyleImages )
- Added the ability to move the close button to the right ( JvTabBar1.CloseButtonRight: = true or false )
- Many fixes to the size and position of text / icons / buttons / scroll

My JvTabBar.pas mod You can **download it here http://pastebin.com/JmbufHy0**

And example source style + JvTabBar.pas **http://www.sendspace.com/file/shhuzr**